How does the extra term and sign change come from in Harold Grad’s derivation of Boltzmann’s equation?
Harold Grad’s method of deriving the Boltzmann equation starts by integrating the Liouville equation:
$$\int_{D_1}\left[{\frac{\partial F_N}{\partial t} +\sum_{i=1}^{N} {\vec{v}_i}.\frac{\partial F_N}{\partial \vec{q}_i}+\sum_{i,j=1}^{N}\frac{\partial \phi_{ij}}{\partial \vec{q}_i}.\frac{\partial F_N}{\partial \vec{p}_i}}\right]d\vec{y}_2..d\vec{y}_N$$
where, $d\vec{y}_i = d\vec{v}_id\vec{q}_i$ and $D_1$ is the region of space where $|\vec{q}_i-\vec{q}_1|\geq \sigma$, and $\sigma$ is a constant, assumed to be equal to molecular diameter.
After integrating the second term, it gives the following expression:
$$\boxed{\vec{v}_1.\frac{\partial F_1^{\sigma}}{\partial \vec{q}_1}+\int_{S_2}d\vec{v}_2F_2^{\sigma}\vec{v_1}.d\vec{S}_2-\int_{S_2}d\vec{v}_2F_2^{\sigma}\vec{v_2}.d\vec{S}_2}$$
It does not match with my calculation using Gauss’s divergence theorem. Please help. My calculation is as follows:
$$\int_{D_1}\left[\sum_{i=1}^{N} {\vec{v}_i}.\frac{\partial F_N}{\partial \vec{q}_i}\right]d\vec{y}_2..d\vec{y}_N$$
$${\vec{v}_1}.\frac{\partial F_1^{\sigma}}{\partial \vec{q}_1}+\int_{D_1}\left[\sum_{i=2}^{N} {\vec{v}_i}.\frac{\partial F_N}{\partial \vec{q}_i}\right]d\vec{y}_2..d\vec{y}_N$$
Using symmetry (meaning labels are not necessary), the above equation can be simplified to:
$${\vec{v}_1}.\frac{\partial F_1^{\sigma}}{\partial \vec{q}_1}+(N-1)\int_{D_1} {\vec{v}_2}.\frac{\partial F_N}{\partial \vec{q}_2}d\vec{y}_2..d\vec{y}_N$$
Now, using Gauss’s divergence theorem (converting volume integral to surface integral) on the space occupied by $d\vec{q}_2=dV_2$ where $dV_2=dq_{2x}dq_{2y}dq_{2z}$, which I got only one term which is the surface integral $\int_{S_2}d\vec{v}_2F_2^{\sigma}\vec{v_2}.d\vec{S}_2$, which makes:
$$\boxed{\vec{v}_1.\frac{\partial F_1^{\sigma}}{\partial \vec{q}_1}+\int_{S_2}d\vec{v}_2F_2^{\sigma}\vec{v_2}.d\vec{S}_2}$$
The first boxed equation is the actual derivation performed by Harold Grad(1949) taken as I studied from Stewart’s book “An Introduction to Boltzmann Equation”. But it doesn’t match with my derivation, please help, where am I wrong?

The minus sign in the third term of the first framed expression is due to the direction of the normal, which was taken outside the sphere $|q_2-q_1| = \sigma$. The second term in the first framed expression arises from the fact that the region $D_1$ depends on $q_1$.
To demonstrate the effect let's consider simplified one-dimensional example. For the function
$$
G^\sigma_1(x) = \int_{|x-y|>\sigma} G^\sigma_2(x,y)dy = \int^{x-\sigma}G^\sigma_2(x,y)dy + \int_{x+\sigma} G^\sigma_2(x,y)dy
$$
we have:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}G^\sigma_1(x) = \int_{|x-y|>\sigma} \frac{\partial}{\partial x}G^\sigma_2(x,y)dy + \left(G_2^\sigma(x,x-\sigma) - G_2^\sigma(x,x+\sigma)\right)
$$
The terms in parentheses on the right side of the last equality are equal to
$$
-\int G_2^\sigma(x,y) dS
$$
in one-dimensional case.
About the last statement. The Gauss's theorem
$$
\int_V \mbox{div}(\vec{F}) d\vec{x} = \int_{\partial V} \vec{F} d\vec{S}
$$
is valid in all spatial dimensions. But in one-dimensional case we have $\vec{x} = x$, $\vec{F}(\vec{x}) = f(x)$, $\mbox{div}(\vec{F}) = f'(x)$, $V = [a,b]$ and
$$
\int_V \mbox{div}(\vec{F}) d\vec{x} = \int_a^b f'(x) dx = f(b) - f(a)
$$
So it is natural to think (or to define) that in this case
$$
\int_{\partial V} fdS = f(b) - f(a).
$$

Thank for finally making some activity on this problem. Could your please expand on your answer because I'm finding it hard to fill the gaps. Also, if possible some diagrams. I shall give you the +200 immediately for atleast making this question alive.

I just noticed this question. I didn't have much time tonight, so I wrote the basic idea in the first iteration, and now I've added a simple example. I'm not sure about the diagrams, but I'll try to fill in the gap if a simple example isn't enough.

So Leibnitz's differentiation under integral is used. But I'm not following how the terms in the parenthesis is nicely packed in a negative surface integral.
